# Button not working when iMessage app is in collapsed state

Tags: ios, swift, imessage

I am trying to implement a button that transitions to another view. The button works when the view is expanded but not when the view is collapsed. Why is this happening?

Note: The same button is in both pictures but the attributes (color, target) only seem to get applied when the view is expanded.

[Not clickable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMzg4.png)

[Clickable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCnzK.png)

Comment: Just edited the post to clarify

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by removing the leading bottom constraint in storyboard. Working as intended.

Comment: It's great that you solved it! And answering your own question is legal and encouraged. But there is nothing about this question-and-answer where the answer in any grows out of the information in the question, so it's not really all that useful for Stack Overflow.